# Extracting info from a playlist in youtube_dl takes extremely long

Tags: python, youtube-dl

I have my python bot that can play music in voice channels. I used YTDLSource class from [here](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/feae059c6858e419552ec4096f1ad2692bb4c484/examples/basic_voice.py#L33) and edited that class to support playlists. Here is my YTDLSource code:

```
youtube_dl.utils.bug_reports_message = lambda: ''

ytdl_format_options = {
    'format': 'bestaudio/best',
    'outtmpl': '%(extractor)s-%(id)s-%(title)s.%(ext)s',
    'restrictfilenames': True,
    'noplaylist': False,
    'nocheckcertificate': True,
    'ignoreerrors': False,
    'logtostderr': False,
    'quiet': True,
    'no_warnings': True,
    'default_search': 'auto',
    'source_address': '0.0.0.0'
}

ffmpeg_options = {
    'options': '-vn',
    "before_options": "-reconnect 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 5"
}

ytdl = youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ytdl_format_options)


class YTDLSource(discord.PCMVolumeTransformer):
    def __init__(self, data, *, volume=0.5):
        super().__init__(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(data['url'], **ffmpeg_options), volume)

        self.data = data

        self.title = data.get('title')
        self.url = data.get('webpage_url')

    @classmethod
    async def get(cls, url, *, volume=0.5):
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

        data = await loop.run_in_executor(None, lambda: ytdl.extract_info(url, download=False))

        if 'entries' in data:
            return [cls(entry, volume=volume) for entry in data['entries']]
        else:
            return cls(data, volume=volume)
```

The code is working, but too slowly. I checked how much time it takes `youtube_dl` to extract the info from a playlist as follows:

```
time1 = time.time()
data = await loop.run_in_executor(None, lambda: ytdl.extract_info(url, download=False))
print(f"Extracted info in {time.time() - time1} seconds")
```

And I got `Extracted info in 12.71654725074768 seconds`. I have tested this with a playlist with 14 tracks from SoundCloud.

Is this behaviour normal with `youtube_dl` or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`youtube_dl` should download and parse data from **every** song in playlist, so it's not surprisingly, it takes so much time.

It's better to load a song that should play next in the queue, so it will be much faster and the problem will be solved.